# Parallel implementation of shortest path in graph_tool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, graph-tool

I want to compute all shortest paths between each pair of nodes in an undirected weighted graph. I am currently using *graph_tool.topology.shortest_distance*, from the graph_tool python library, but it seems to be running in one core only. Is there a way to make it run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

graph-tool uses the [boost graph library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) for its shortest path algorithms, but doesn't use [its parallel graph library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/graph_parallel/doc/html/index.html), as far as I know.

You could try calling the parallel library from python using some methods referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python).

Alternatively, you could try [JuliaGraphs's parallel implementations](https://juliagraphs.org/Graphs.jl/dev/parallel/) in Julia.